# how to upload image in form using code netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Am writing an ID CARD processing app in java but am having problem with the code that will upload and display a client image in a label i created for picture. the only thing am getting with the code below is the image path but not the image it self.

This is the code i have attempted so far.

```
FileFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("images","jpeg");
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(ff);
        int open = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (open == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            java.io.File path = fc.getSelectedFile();

            String file_name = path.toString();

            pathe.setText(file_name);

            java.io.File image = fc.getSelectedFile();

            ImageIcon photo = new ImageIcon(image.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Please supply the code you've attempted so far

Comment: The code above is what i have so far and really need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
The code that does the magic is below

      FileFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("images","jpeg");
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(ff);
        int open = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (open == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            java.io.File path = fc.getSelectedFile();

            String file_name = path.toString();

            pathe.setText(file_name);

          BufferedImage bi; // bi is the object of the class BufferedImage
// Now you use try and catch `enter code here`

try{
bi = ImageIO.read(path); // path is your file or image path
jlabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(bi));
}catch(IOException e){ }
```